# Declaring a variable of class type without initializing it

Tags: java

I read somewhere, while reading about the `System.out.print` that in the `System` class, there is a declaration of 'out' as a `PrintStream` class type static variable as follows: `public static final PrintStream out;`

This invoked a question in me that what exactly happens if we just declare a variable of a certain class type and not initialize it by not calling any constructor? In above example 'out' is declared static and final, but I am looking for a generalized answer.

Comment: `System.out` (along with in and err) is the one exception. It's supposedly a `final` field but its value can be changed (indirectly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an object and store it in a variable, you don't actually store it. You only get a pointer to a specific memory address, where the object is currently located.

If you don't initialize an object, you get a null pointer. That object simply doesn't exist, there are are no fields or methods in it.

Static fields and methods are different, they aren't connected to an instance of an object, they're connected to the class (this is one of the many reasons using static is a bad practise). They can be accesed from anywhere at anytime.

Comment: 'they're connected to the class' - that is why we can call 'out' as System.out as its a class variable, understood, but if 'out' is a null pointer or reference, how are we able to call a method 'print' of `PrintStream` class through 'out' as in `System.out.print`?

Comment: But how its already initialized? @JonSkeet also says this in the first answer to this question:- "Then like any other field, it starts off with its default value - which for references types (classes, interfaces, enums) is the null reference." So, I assume he meant that its a null reference/pointer.

Comment: @amsquareb `public static out = new PrintStream(...)`

Comment: But I have read that it is like `public static final PrintStream out;` as also mentioned in the question. Have I read incorrect info.?

Comment: @amsquareb It gets initialized later in the class

Comment: Thanks a lot, there in lied the whole confusion!

Answer (score 4):

> This invoked a question in me that what exactly happens if we just declare a variable of a certain class type and not initialize it by not calling any constructor?

Then like any other field, it starts off with its default value - which for references types (classes, interfaces, enums) is the `null` reference. From [section 4.12.5 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>
> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
> - For type `byte`, the default value is zero, that is, the value of `(byte)0`.
> - For type `short`, the default value is zero, that is, the value of `(short)0`.
> - For type `int`, the default value is zero, that is, `0`.
> - For type `long`, the default value is zero, that is, `0L`.
> - For type `float`, the default value is positive zero, that is, `0.0f`.
> - For type `double`, the default value is positive zero, that is, `0.0d`.
> - For type `char`, the default value is the null character, that is, `'\u0000'`.
> - For type `boolean`, the default value is `false`.
> - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is `null`.

`System.out` is a bit special - it's final, but can be changed via `System.setOut`. I would try to avoid generalizing any other behaviour based on that.